# Displaying images on Chromecast's Custom Receiver

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast

I'm currently trying to make my own Custom Receiver on a Chromecast based project. After thinking about building it from scratch, I chose to use the sample provided [here](https://github.com/googlecast/CastReferencePlayer) since I'm a beginner in JS and that I couldn't find any guide or tutorial on how to build it.

Now after some tests and research, I understood that the sample custom receiver hasn't any image display functionalities built-in and that I have to write the logic myself.

However the documentation provided ([here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver) and [there](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/)) isn't clear enough for my understanding and I don't get what I *need* to implement and what isn't necessary. It only explains what functions do but not when you should use them.

So what I understood is:

- I have to place an `<img src="" />` tag in the html file to display the images.
- There is no state when you display images
- The functionnalities are very limited when manipulating images

From what I understood of the code, in the `sampleplayer.CastPlayer` constructor we create the mediaElement_ like this: `this.mediaElement_ = (this.element_.querySelector('video'));`.

We then use it to create the mediaManager_:
`this.mediaManager_ = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(this.mediaElement_);`.

But then how do I do to include the image part? Should I create something like a `this.imageElement_` in the same fashion as the mediaElement?
Then what do I pass to the `mediaManager_`?
Do I have to create a second manager for images only?

I read that someone wrote a function like this:

```
sampleplayer.CastPlayer.prototype.loadImage_ = function(info) {
    this.log_('loadImage_');
    var url = info.message.media.contentId;
    document.getElementById("androidImage").src=url;
    this.setState_(sampleplayer.State.PLAYING, true); //That's not good according to answers
};
```

It seems to have worked for him but I don't know what he did in the rest of the code...

It might look like silly questions to you but it is very unclear to me.

Could you help me figuring out the steps/functions I have to implement?
An answer like:

> In the CastPlayer constructor you should:
>   - Add this.
>   - Modify that.
>   Add a ____ function to display the image
>   Create a message Bus like so: ______

Would be awesome :)

Thx in advance.

Comment: does your html tag have some `id` associated with it? like so `<img src="" id="someId"/>`, in the example you have given that id would be `androidImage` so basically you are grabbing the document `id` and replacing the `src` which would be your image source

Comment: I guess it will have an id to replace its src yes. The thing I don't understand is: how do I send this img element to the mediaManager_ so it can handle it when it receives data?